# How can I understand these limits?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I would like to see a proof of these limits:

$$ \lim_{x\to 1^-} \left(\sin x\right)^{\frac{1}{1-x}}=0,\qquad \lim_{x\to 1^+} \left(\sin x\right)^{\frac{1}{1-x}}=+\infty. $$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try replacing $\sin x$ with a constant $\alpha$ satisfying $0 < \alpha < 1$, and see if you can prove the same limits. Then use the fact that near $x=1$, we have $\sin x \approx \sin 1 \approx 0.54$.

Comment: For the OP: are you able to show that if $C\in(1,+\infty)$, then $$\lim_{z\to +\infty} C^z = +\infty,\qquad \lim_{z\to -\infty} C^z = 0$$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "proof"? Do you want to prove the limits by definition or simply solve those limits?

Answer (score 0):

$\log\lim_{x\to 1^-} \left(\sin x\right)^{\frac{1}{1-x}}=\lim_{x\to 1^-} \log\left(\sin x\right)^{\frac{1}{1-x}}=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}\right)\log\sin x=\infty\cdot \log\sin 1=-\infty$

If the $\log$ tends to $-\infty$ the limit is $0$ because $e^x\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$

In a similar way you can do for the other limit. Be careful because $\lim_{x\to 1^+}\dfrac{1}{1-x}=-\infty$